# ode45 Output Vector and Initial Condition Vector

Tags: matlab, function, vector, ode

Here is the error message I am receiving upon running my code:

```
Error using odearguments (line 92)
@(T,Y,P)THREE_BODY_GRAV(T,Y,[4*PI^2,1,3.0135E-6,3.693E-8]) returns a vector of length
12, but the length of initial conditions vector is 8. The vector returned by
@(T,Y,P)THREE_BODY_GRAV(T,Y,[4*PI^2,1,3.0135E-6,3.693E-8]) and the initial conditions
vector must have the same number of elements.
```

I don't understand why the output vector would be of length 12. The problem I am trying to solve is the three body gravitational system, in which the earth and moon orbit about the stationary sun. Here is my preliminary work (defining the functions, etc):

```
syms x_SE y_SE x_SM y_SM x_EM y_EM v_Ex v_Ey v_Mx v_My Ms Me Mm G t

r_SE = [x_SE;y_SE]
r_SM = [x_SM;y_SM]
x_EM = x_SE - x_SM
y_EM = y_SE - y_SM
r_EM = [x_EM;y_EM]

eqs_1 = -(Ms*G*x_SE)./(r_SE).^3-(Mm*G*x_EM)./(r_EM).^3
eqs_2 = -(Ms*G*y_SE)./(r_SE).^3-(Mm*G*y_EM)./(r_EM).^3
eqs_3 = -(Ms*G*x_SM)./(r_SM).^3-(Me*x_EM)./(r_EM).^3
eqs_4 = -(Ms*G*y_SM)./(r_SM).^3-(Me*y_EM)./(r_EM).^3

eqs = [eqs_1;v_Ex;eqs_2;v_Ey;eqs_3;v_Mx;eqs_4;v_My]

matlabFunction(eqs,'vars',{t,[v_Ex;x_SE;v_Ey;y_SE;v_Mx;x_SM;v_My;y_SM],...
                   [G,Ms,Me,Mm]},'file','three_body_grav')
```

Looking back at this, I now realize that I poorly named the variables; but let me attempt at describing each one. `r_SE` is the vector that points from the sun to the earth; `r_SM` is the vector that points between the sun and moon; `r_EM` is the vector that points from the earth to the moon; `eqs1` to `eqs4` are the accelerations of the earth and moon in the x and y directions; and `eqs` is just a column vector to store these unknown function. `v_Ex` and `v_Ey` are the x and y direction velocities of the earth.

I then used `matlabFunction` to define, which it seemed to do properly. However, once I reached the point in which I wanted to approximate the unknown functions, so that I can get the positions as a function of time, I received the error I alluded to above. Here is what I ran:

```
[tout,yout] = ode45(@(t,Y,P)three_body_grav(t,Y,[4*pi^2,1,3.0135e-6,3.693e-8]),...
                    [0,1],[0;1;1;0;0;1;1;0],myoptions);
```

To my understanding, there should only be eight initial conditions: one for `v_Ex` (initial x velocity of earth), `x_SE` (initial positon of the earth), `v_Ey` (initial y velocity of the earth); `y_SE` (initial y position of the earth), `v_Mx` (initial x velocity of the moon), `x_SM` (initial x position of the moon), `v_My` (initial y velocity of the moon), `y_SM` (initial y position of the moon).

Could some possible interpret my error?

EDIT: I was able to fix it. Here is the updated code:

```
syms x_E y_E x_M y_M x_EM y_EM v_Ex v_Ey v_Mx v_My Ms Me Mm G t

r_E = [x_E;y_E]

mag_r_E = sqrt(r_E.'*r_E)

r_M = [x_M;y_M]

mag_r_M = sqrt(r_M.'*r_M)

r_EM = r_E - r_M

mag_r_EM = sqrt(r_EM.'*r_EM)

eqs_1 = -(Ms*G*x_E)./(mag_r_E).^3-(Mm*G*(x_E-x_M))./(mag_r_EM).^3

eqs_2 = -(Ms*G*y_E)./(mag_r_E).^3-(Mm*G*(y_E-y_M))./(mag_r_EM).^3

eqs_3 = -(Ms*G*x_M)./(mag_r_M).^3-(Me*G*(x_E-x_M))./(mag_r_EM).^3

eqs_4 = -(Ms*G*y_M)./(mag_r_M).^3-(Me*G*(y_E-y_M))./(mag_r_EM).^3

eqs = [eqs_1;v_Ex;eqs_2;v_Ey;eqs_3;v_Mx;eqs_4;v_My]

matlabFunction(eqs,'vars',{t,[v_Ex;x_E;v_Ey;y_E;v_Mx;x_M;v_My;y_M],[G,Ms,Me,Mm]},'file','three_body_grav')
```

The problem was that I was dividing by a vector; and in Newton's law of gravity, we are supposed to divide by the magnitude of the distance vector.

However, now I am having another difficulty. When I use

```
[tout,yout] = ode45(@(t,Y,P) three_body_grav(t,Y,[4*pi^2,1,3.0135e-6,3.693e-8]),[0,1],[0;1;1;0;0;1;1;0],myoptions);
```

to solve the unknown functions, all but the first element in the output vector is a 'NaN.' For instance,

```
 yout(:,1)

ans =

     0
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
```

Comment: Please include the line where you use `syms` to create your variables so your code is runnable. I'd recommend some simple debugging: printing out and comparing the dimensions of `eqs` and `[v_Ex;x_SE;v_Ey;y_SE;v_Mx;x_SM;v_My;y_SM]`.

Comment: @horchler I just edited my post.

Comment: I just compared the dimensions, and eqs is a 12x1 and [v_Ex;x_SE;v_Ey;y_SE;v_Mx;x_SM;v_My;y_SM] is an 8x1. So, I looked back at the contents of eqs, and eqs_1 is a 2x1 matrix. Why is that so? I don't want it to be 2x1, I want it to be eqs_1 just to be a variable. Also, I looked at each individual element of eqs_1, and this is what I got: eqs_1(1,1) = - (G*Mm)/(x_SE - x_SM)^2 - (G*Ms)/x_SE^2 ...and... eqs_1(2,1) =  - (G*Ms*x_SE)/y_SE^3 - (G*Mm*(x_SE - x_SM))/(y_SE - y_SM)^3

Comment: So, how can redefine this variables so that I get eqs_1 as being a 2x1 vector? What define a new variable that takes the magnitude of R_SE, r_SM, and R_EM?

Comment: But I don't want it to be, because that then changes the length of the output vector, and the amount of initial conditions I need.

Comment: Polar coordinates? `r = sqrt(x^2+y^2)`. I think you should figure out your equations of motion (physics/mechanics), attempt to program this again, and come back if you still can't get it to work.

Comment: @horchler All right, I was able to fix the issue; however, another has arisen. Could you possibly take a gander?

Comment: Well, how does a `NaN` arise? Common ways are `0/0`, `Inf/Inf`, or `Inf-Inf`. The first seems likely in your case. I'd make sure your initial conditions are correct and correspond the right equations. Run `y0=[0;1;1;0;0;1;1;0];` `p=[4*pi^2,1,3.0135e-6,3.693e-8]` `three_body_grav(0,y0,p)` to evaluate your system at the initial conditions. And maybe it would be a good idea to learn how to write your own integration function rather than using `matlabFunction`, which just seems to be causing you confusion.

Comment: Of course. The initial conditions I chose incurred division by zero! I think that should be everything. Thank you very much, @horchler, for your patience and understanding